# Creating multiple enterprise application registrations in a one tenant to same web application

Tags: .net, azure, security, identity, registration

Our .NET Core Web application is a multi-tenant application that defines specific roles in the application registration in the host tenant. Customers enroll to subscribe with this application which creates an enterprise application registration in the customer tenant.

Our challenge is that the customer is large and wants to define a set of users for roles for one subscription but wants to use the same application for a second group but under a second subscription.

Is it possible to setup a second enterprise application registration in the customer's Azure AD tenant so that a second set of roles are exposed for the second user group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Every service principal(i.e. enterprise application) in other tenants has the same `client id` with the corresponding AD App in the home tenant, but there could not be more than one service principal with the same `client id` in one AAD tenant.